# TextBox.Text doesn't change after edit when TextBox is inside Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, postdata

The following code used to work as expected until recently:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView1" OnDataBound="FormView_OnDataBound" DefaultMode="Edit"
        OnItemUpdating="FormView1_OnItemUpdating"
        DataSourceID="FormViewDsObjectDS">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterOfRepeaters" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterOfRepeaters_OnItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="TextBoxRepeater" OnItemDataBound="TextBoxRepeater_OnItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="textLabel" Text='<%# Bind ("LabelText") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox" Text='<%# Bind ("Value") %>' OnTextChanged="txtBox_OnTextChanged" OnUnload="txtBox_OnUnload"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="noBindTxtBox" Text="initial value" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="submitButton" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></telerik:RadButton>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

I noticed that my `txtBox.Text` property is not updated in code behind after an edit when `submitButton` is pressed. Nor does `noBindTxtBox.Text` is updated as well. Since I am not the only one who is developing application I believe it may be a side effect of some other changes in the application. Aforementioned example works fine if extracted into a test application.

At the moment I am out of ideas how to pinpoint an exact problem which entails such behaviour. It seems like a lifecycle issue.

Since I am not an expert in asp.net maybe you could throw out some debugging/tracing ideas that would help me identify an issue?

By the way in `FormView1_OnItemUpdating` method I extract `txtBox.Text` value on `submitButton` click and it is not changed. The same is inside `txtBox_OnUnload` method. And `txtBox_OnTextChanged` is not even called after submit button click.

*Update 2014-03-18*

I subclassed `RadTextBox` in order to check whether the posted back data contains edited value or not.

```
public class RRadTextBox : RadTextBox {
    protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postCollection){
        return base.LoadPostData (postDataKey, postCollection);
    }
}
```

It turns out that it does not contain updated text box value. That is, `postCollection[postDataKey]` value is the same as initially set even after changing text box value. Does anybody know under which circumstances `LoadPostData` does not contain updated value just initial one?

*Update 2014-03-19*

When `RRadTextBox` is added directly in the form view `EditItemTemplate` I can see updated `Text` property value in `LoadPostData` method.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
        <serverControls:RRadTextBox runat="server" ID="directRRadTxtBox" Text="initial Text"/>
```

I would like to add that `FormView` is bound not in a `PageLoad` event but `OnClick` of a button. Thus repeaters are not bound during an edit.

Comment: txtBox_OnTextChanged should be fired when user changes the text on txtBox, right?

Comment: Yes, but only during a postback. If `AutoPostBack` option is enabled it fires when control looses focus. In my case `txtBox_OnTextChanged` method is only invoked when `AutoPostBack` is set to `true' and I can see the textbox changes. However I am looking why it doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: Hm, and where is SO wisdom when you need it the most :)

Comment: the problem sounds simple, but the explanation making it tough to solve. I have experience difficulty in getting the change text value with AutoPostBack on. But for you the case seems different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `Repeater` and `FormView` controls in this particular case. Apparently I had a JavaScript function which reset all text input controls created by the `Repeater` to their default values. This reset JS function was executed on the dialog close event. Furthermore I used to close the dialog which contained edit form in question together with a submit button click. Thus I couldn't see updated values in `LoadPostData` because they weren't there.